# Is there a closed form solution for the motion of a particle with friction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, vectors

I am trying to find a solution to Newton's equation of motion $ \boldsymbol{F} = m \boldsymbol{\ddot{r}} $ assuming a constant force $ \boldsymbol{F} $ but accounting for kinetic friction which is a force of constant magnitude $ \mu_{\mathrm{k}}\, g \, m $ and opposing the velocity.

$$ \boldsymbol{F} - \mu_{\mathrm{k}}\, g \, m \frac{\boldsymbol{\dot{r}}}{\| \boldsymbol{\dot{r}} \|} = m \boldsymbol{\ddot{r}} $$

I tried approximating $ \| \boldsymbol{\dot{r}} \| $ with $ \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\dot{r}}^{2} + \epsilon} $ but failed to find a solution. Is there a closed form solution? If not, is there an *easy* way to prove this? How would one construct a approximation of the solution?

Comment: You can get somewhat simplified equations if you use the $(r,\theta)$ coordinates. Then also, the equations will be far from solvable. On the top of that if you impose some conditions like the radial velocity component negligible compared to the angular one etc. then you might be able to get some closed form expression.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I don't think I can make any additional assumptions. I am trying to add friction support to a particle simulator and while this allows the assumption that the force is constant during a time step and only requires evaluating the equation for small times there is not much that can be assumed about the relation of forces, accelerations and velocities. The particle may be almost at rest but being accelerate by a large force or it may move at high speed with only tiny forces acting upon it.